# How to get the textbox value which is added(value) dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have an empty text box on page load, using jquery I will add text to that text box.

Now I want to retrieve the text on the server side when Button click function happened

**code**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPaths" runat="server" Width="550px" Height="19px" CssClass="txtPathClass" Enabled="False" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPaths').val("Testing");
```

**ServerCode**

```
protected void btnUpload_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string txtPathss = txtPaths.Text;
    Debug.writeline("txtPathss = "+txtPaths.Text);
}
```

**Note**

> The problem is I cannot get the value of `txtPaths.text` value

It is printing like

```
txtPathss =
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem you're having?

Comment: Please do share the problem/issue while posting the question.

Comment: That should not be a problem with the code you have now...

Comment: Note that `Enabled="False"` prevents the value posted during form submit - use `ReadOnly="true"` instead.

Comment: I think in this case it would be beneficial to see some more of your form code, instead of just the textbox. When you run your form, you do see the text being set?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `Enabled="False"` prevents the textbox value from being inserted during form submit, because it adding `disabled="disabled"` attribute to the textbox (see the reference below). You should use `ReadOnly="True"` setting by changing this one:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPaths" runat="server" Width="550px" Height="19px" CssClass="txtPathClass" Enabled="false" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

to this one:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPaths" runat="server" Width="550px" Height="19px" CssClass="txtPathClass" AutoPostBack="true" ReadOnly="true" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

By using `readonly` attribute, the input cannot be edited by client user but its value still available during form submit.

**Note:**

In addition to setting `ReadOnly` to prevent user input, you should enable postback by setting `AutoPostBack="true"`.

References:

[WebControl.Enabled Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[TextBox.ReadOnly Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.readonly?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: still it is not printing anything

Comment: Try setting `AutoPostBack="true"` to enable postback state.

Comment: I added `AutoPostBack=true`. I also check `$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnUpload").click(function () {
        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPaths').val("Testing");
        alert("textbox == "+$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPaths').val());
    })`  It is showing `Testing` in alert. But I cannot get the value on server side